# Python Selenium find element which contains specific text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem. I want to find the login page of several websites using Selenium. To do this, I try to go to the page and click the button with text such as "sign in", "login", and so on. This worked for Netflix. Example:

Code Website: Netflix.com

```
<a href="/login" class="authLinks redButton" data-uia="header-login-link">Sign In</a>
```

My Code to detect the button:

```
result = "https://www.microsoft.com"

driver.get(result)

elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In').click

print(driver.current_url) # returns the website: https://www.netflix.com/de-en/login
```

Now I try this with the website Microsoft.com. Website code as image:

[image: WEBSITE CODE MICROSOFT]

If I now change my contains query to:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in').click # small "in"
```

Selenium does not find any element. I have tried many different options that Selenium offers such as:

1. find_element_by_id
2. find_element_by_name
3. find_element_by_link_text
4. ...

eg: [https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html]

My goal is to use the textual information like "sign in, login" etc. to find the button and press it.

I would be very grateful for your help

Answer (score 2):

See the issue here is with `Netflix.com` , you have a HTML like this :

```
<a href="/login" class="authLinks redButton" data-uia="header-login-link">Sign In</a>
```

see the tag, it is `a`, which is an anchor tag in HTML.

`find_element_by_link_text`, or `find_element_by_partial_link_text` look for text between anchor tag.

But when you go to `Microsoft.com`

```
<div class="mectrl_header_text mectrl_truncate">Sign in</div>
```

`Sign in` is wrapped inside `div`. so `find_element_by_link_text` or `find_element_by_partial_link_text` will not work.

instead you can try with below xpath :-

```
//div[text()='Sign in']
```

in code :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Sign in']").click()
```

or you can give it a try with Explicit waits as well :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Sign in']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

As described by cruisepandey for these two particular cases, `find_element_by_link_text` will work in some cases but in some other cases will not.
While locating element by it's text will work for all these case.
So I never use `find_element_by_link_text` or by partial text methods, just using `find_element_by_xpath` method based on element's text and it works fine.
In your case you can use

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Sign in']"))).click()
```

This will be more simple, stable and reliable.